# How to ignore assigning /dev/cdrom to specific device?

Tags: 10.04, usb, 64-bit, hal

I have a HDSPA USB stick from Vodafone for mobile broadband, a [HUAWEI model K3520](http://www.business.vodafone.com/site/bus/public/enuk/support/10_productsupport/usb_stick/01_vodafone/05_vodafone_k3520/05_summary/p_summary.jsp) (in some places also designated E169 I think) which works just fine in Ubuntu 10.04 "Lucid" (*amd64*). This device is automatically mounted as a CD-ROM device by Ubuntu -- supposedly by the HAL daemon, *hald* -- namely the "partition" containing the device-specific software.

The contents of the auto-mounted partition (upon inserting the stick in a USB port):

```
ubuntu@lucid:~$ ls -lh /media/VMC\ LITE*/
total 37M
-r-------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   70 2008-03-13 19:39 Autorun.inf
-r-------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  36M 2008-04-14 19:28 helper.exe
-r-------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 316K 2008-03-13 17:33 setup.exe
ubuntu@lucid:~$
```

The symlink `/dev/cdrom` gets assigned from the CD-ROM device at `/dev/sr0` to the device `/dev/sr1` upon detection of the USB stick,

```
ubuntu@lucid:~$ ls -lh /dev/cdrom
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 2011-04-27 22:48 /dev/cdrom -> sr1
ubuntu@lucid:~$ ls -lh /dev/sr*
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 2011-04-27 22:34 /dev/sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 1 2011-04-27 22:48 /dev/sr1
ubuntu@lucid:~$
```

which although not a serious impediment it is nevertheless an annoyance. For example, in the console this forces specifying `eject -d /dev/sr0` to open the CD-ROM tray, instead of a simple `eject`; supposedly, other programs wanting to use the genuine CD-ROM drive will require specifying explicitly the device instead of "assuming" the symlink `/dev/cdrom` to point to the "correct" device.

I have tried to follow instructions from a [Arch Linux thread about hald](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=25500), by creating my own configuration as `/etc/hal/fdi/policy/cdrom.fdi` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deviceinfo version="0.2">
  <device>
    <match key="block.storage_device" string="/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/storage_model_CDDVDW_SH_S223C">
      <merge key="volume.policy.should_mount" type="bool">true</merge>
      <merge key="volume.policy.desired_mount_point" type="string">cdrom</merge>
    </match>
  </device>
  <device>
    <match key="storage.vendor" string="HUAWEI">
      <match key="storage.model" string="Mass Storage">
        <match key="storage.bus" string="usb">
          <match key="storage.drive_type" string="cdrom">
            <merge key="volume.policy.should_mount" type="bool">false</merge>
          </match>
        </match>
      </match>
    </match>
  </device>
</deviceinfo>
```

in an unsuccesful attempt to "coherce" *hald* into always assigning `/dev/sr0` to `/dev/cdrom` instead of auto-mounting the USB stick on insertion.

I realize that I could use `gconf-editor` to toggle the key `/apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount`, but that would affect *all* media -- which is not quite what I'm looking for, although given the low impact of this "annoyance" it might be an acceptable compromise.

However, I am looking at some insight into what *hald* configuration might yield the desired results -- ignoring assigning `/dev/sr1` (the USB stick) to `/dev/cdrom` and thereby maintaining the symlink of `/dev/cdrom` to `/dev/sr0` (the CD-ROM drive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming of the cdrom devices is configured in
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules . In my version of the file
there are four lines that create the cdrom, cdrw, dvd and dvdrw
symlinks, all pointing to the same drive:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_CDROM}=="?*", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-2:0:0:0", SYMLINK+="cdrom", ENV{GENERATED}="1"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_CDROM}=="?*", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-2:0:0:0", SYMLINK+="cdrw", ENV{GENERATED}="1"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_CDROM}=="?*", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-2:0:0:0", SYMLINK+="dvd", ENV{GENERATED}="1"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_CDROM}=="?*", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-2:0:0:0", SYMLINK+="dvdrw", ENV{GENERATED}="1"
```

What do these lines do? They test some things with the `==` operator, and
then they add (`+=`) a symlink or set (`=`) the environment variable GENERATED.

You want to insert a new test there, so that your HSDPA stick is ignored.

So you need to find a unique attribute of your device. You can run
`lsusb` in the terminal and look if you find your HSDPA stick there. 
And you can also ask udev itsself, e.g. with

```
udevadm info --export-db | less
```

(In "less" you can search with the / key, and quit with q.)
Try to find a unique attribute, like ID_SERIAL, ID_VENDOR_ID or ID_MODEL_ID.
The hex numbers in ID_VENDOR_ID and ID_MODEL_ID are the same numbers as in the output of `lsusb`.

If you have found something unique, insert a new test in the udev lines, comparing for inequality with the `!=` operator:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_CDROM}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="_USB_DISK_Pro_075A06420103-0:1", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-2:0:0:0", SYMLINK+="cdrom", ENV{GENERATED}="1"
```

Save the file, eject the USB stick, plug it in again and hope that it is working.

Comment: Unfortunately I am very unfamiliar with the workings of udev. The tip on the 70-persistent-cd.rules file was exactly what I was looking for. There was already a rule for the USB HDSPA stick, and I merely changed the value of the respective `SYMLINK` parameter for something other than "cdrom". The `eject` command no longer appears to be confusing the two. Thanks elmicha!

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with writing some udev rules for your device.
I'm not an expert on the topic, but you might want to research on these links:

- http://blog.pucp.edu.pe/item/88256
- http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev
- http://noenieto.com/blog/udev-en-linux

That's all I know. Hope it helps.